# Modify MSSQL Statement for Webpage

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, content-management-system

I've created a simple database for my website and it has a content management system wherein the admin can add items, which will eventually be stored in the database. But I've noticed a problem, whenever i'm testing out adding new items to my website, The id column continues to increment after deleting and adding a new item again. Lets say I have 8 fixed items on my database that has the 1-8 id respectively. I will now create the 9th item which will give me the id 9, but when i delete it and create a new item, the id number will be 10 so and so forth. What i want to happen is for the id to stay in number 9.

Here is an image of my data overview:

[image]

As you can see, my 9th item has an id of 22, which is not the result that we want.

And here is my SQL Statement:

```
        /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[guitarItem]    Script Date: 21/10/2016    15:20:18 ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   SET ANSI_PADDING ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[guitarItem](
      [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
      [model] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
      [price] [float] NOT NULL,
      [image1] [varchar](255) NULL,
      [image2] [varchar](255) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
    [id] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
   SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ON
    INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2]) VALUES (1, N'Ibanez', N'ARZ307', 9000.00 , N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezARZ307.jpg', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezARZ307StandingPosition.png')
    INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2]) VALUES (2, N'Ibanez', N'DT420TCR', 11000.00, N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezDTR420TCR.jpg', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezDTR420TCRStandingPosition.png')
    INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2])    VALUES (3, N'Ibanez', N'JBM100', 18000.00, N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezJBM100.jpg', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Brands/ibanezJBM100StandingPosition.png')
   INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1],   [image2]) VALUES (4, N'Ibanez', N'M8M', 13000.00, N'../Images/Guitar   Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezM8M.png', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez   Guitars/ibanezM8MStandingPosition.png')
  INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2]) VALUES (5, N'Ibanez', N'RGAIX7FM', 15000.00, N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezRGAIX7FM.jpg', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezRGAIX7FMStandingPosition.png')
    INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2]) VALUES (6, N'Ibanez', N'JEM77P', 30000.00, N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezJEM77P.jpg', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez   Guitars/ibanezJEM77PStandingPosition.png')
   INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2])    VALUES (7, N'Ibanez', N'AR325', 8000.00, N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez   Guitars/ibanezAR325.jpg', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez  Guitars/ibanezAR325StandingPosition.png')
    INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] ([id], [type], [model], [price], [image1], [image2])     VALUES (8, N'Ibanez', N'PGM3', 36000.00, N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez    Guitars/ibanezPGM3.jpg', N'../Images/Guitar Brands/Ibanez   Guitars/ibanezPGM3StandingPosition.png')


 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[guitarItem] OFF
```

Comment: I assume that the grid is setup to directly save any changes made to it to the database. Any changes done to the grid is therefor also done to the table the grid is based on. That is why the number keeps change. The field with identity is incremented every time data is added. It is not decreased after a delete is done.

Comment: what should i modify in the grid??

Comment: Short answer yes. But it requires some work: First table field id should not be an identity field. The update save should be linked to a stored procedure which should for inserts first retrieve the next available id  and then insert the new value.

Comment: So it means all i have to do is remove the identity so that i can edit it?? The ability to increment tho will be gone. But i guess its the best way for now.

Comment: No. You will have to take care of it separately in the insert side. It is just not automated.

Comment: can you show some example? sorry im still a beginner in databases.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a list of possible examples. Both for SQL and ASP.Net:
(Some also reference other resources)

**ASP.NET**

[Stored Procedure with parameters into DataGridView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841995/stored-procedure-with-parameters-into-datagridview-in-c-sharp)
[Populate DataGridView from a Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927822/populate-datagridview-from-a-stored-procedure)
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/396443/Displaying-results-from-a-stored-procedure-into-da
http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/procedure.htm

**SQL**

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/126898/sql-server-how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-in-sql
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure-tutorial/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx

*Use google/bing if the mentioned links do not provide enough examples.*

phrases:

- sql stored procedures
- datagridview linked to sql stored procedures